# Dockerfile COPY from a Windows file system to a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have a simple **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
LABEL maintainer="rburton@agsource.com"
COPY C:/Users/rburton/code/MyAgsourceAPI /var/www
```

It is the last line that is giving me problems. I am copying from a Windows structure to a docker container (Linux I assume). When I build this image I get:

```
...
Step 3/3 : COPY C:/Users/rburton/code/MyAgsourceAPI /var/www
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/dockerbuilder720374851/C:/Users/rburton/code/MyAgsourceAPI: no such file or directory
```

First, something is preventing the recognition that this is an absolute path and naturally if the path is pre-pended with `/var/lib/docker/tmp/dockerbuilder720374851` then the file will not be found. Second, I have tried `/` and `\` but all with the same result. Also the drive letter I suspect is confusing to docker. So the question is how do I copy files and folders (along with the contents) from a Windows folder to a docker container?

Comment: The path you copy from has to be relative from the build context (the . in docker build .). It cannot be an arbitrary path on the system outside of the build context [docker-forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/copy-files-from-windows-host-to-ubuntu-container/28757)

Comment: The error that I am getting is:

Step 3/3 : COPY MyAgsourceAPI/ /var/www
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder894919783/MyAgsourceAPI: no such file or directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, change your `Dockerfile` to:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
LABEL maintainer="rburton@agsource.com"
COPY MyAgsourceAPI /var/www
```

Then, to go your `code` directory: `cd Users/rburton/code`.

**Within** that directory, run:
`docker build -t <image_name> .`

Comment: Thank you. I originally moved the Dockerfile to C:\Temp because I was running up against a "could not stat" error that was supposedly solved by moving to folder that didn't have sub-folders. But now this seems to work.

Comment: Theres a joke, where a person only knows enough english, to tell someone to 'come here' - so if he wants someone to go somewhere, he goes to the place and then says, 'come here' -- jokes aside, how do you write absolute paths?

Comment: ok, the file referenced in the dockerfile has to be 1) Relative to the docker file 2) Has to be inside or lower than the docker-file folder - cannot be higher than that.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the path is relative to the Dockerfile and not your Windows filesystem.

If for example your filesystem is layed out like this:

```
+-+-MyProject
  |
  +---Dockerfile
  |
  +-+-build
    |
    +---MyAgsourceAPI
```

You can use:

```
COPY /build/MyAgsourceAPI /var/www
```

Note that "MyProject" (or anything above it) is excluded from the path.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip that might be helpful, I've seen same issue while running build from correct context, and issue remained until I've used all small caps on src folder that I wanted to copy from. eg:

```
COPY MyAgsourceAPI /var/www -> COPY myagsourceapi /var/www
```