# Docker starts looking for src folder in wrong directory

Tags: docker

So, I am new to Docker but after trying a couple of times I can't get this to work.

Basically I have a simple script like this:

Dockerfile

```
from centos:7
.....
COPY /C:/Users/Kalin/Drive/web/sites/foo.com/ /var/www
EXPOSE 80
```

Whenever I run docker build everything works as planned except at the COPY part I get this error:

```
Step 10/11 : COPY /C:/Users/Kalin/Drive/web/sites/foo.com/ /var/www
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder646917435/C:/Users/Kalin/Drive/web/Kalin/foo.com: no such file or directory
```

I get the error is about not finding a directory, but instead of looking for it starting from `C:/..` foldedr it is looking from `/var/...`

I don't know what mistake I am doing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile COPY from a Windows file system to a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309423/dockerfile-copy-from-a-windows-file-system-to-a-docker-container)

Comment: For the source path, you need to use a relative path from the directory you're currently in.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to make relative path in `COPY` command so if you have your docker file in `/C:/Users/Kalin` and you are running docker build from that folder, just place `Drive/web/sites/foo.com/` in `COPY` command